# snap to object with mirror modifier

Tags: snapping

i create a simple shape (see the attachment ) then i just simply apply mirror midifier to have a complete closed object (the original object is the one 
in wireframe shading). Now i add a plane and i want to snap the base of the object to the plane so it will sit on top of the plane. What is the best way to do it ? because of the mirror modifier, the bottom face is not selectable, in edit mode i can't snap the 3d cursor to the bottom face.

Thanks.

edit :

here's the blend file :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ntfEzOrnE95jsHNxzcG8sUVDu_-ioqbp/view?usp=sharing

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enable [snapping](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#transform-snapping) and choose face mode. Then select the plane, go to bottom view press T > 0 to translate it on the spot. It will snap to the face which is nearest to the current view, in this case the desired bottom face.

Comment: @Leander  ..  could you expand on that? I've not heard of it and can't get it to work.

Comment: @Robin [Does this help?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJDKd.gif)

Comment: @Leander  Thanks for your trouble .. I can get it to snap OK .. it was the shortcuts I couldn't get.. are they some of your own?

Comment: @Robin Sorry, I meant to write G > X for **T**ranslation and got confused.

Comment: @Leander Hi, i've just added the blend file (pls check my post) , so everyone can test. I still can't make it work. can you explain with my blend file test ? i can snap the box with no problem, but can't applied it to my mirrored object.

Comment: Currently, the snapping only works exactly under the mouse cursor. To change that, enable [Project individual elements on the surface of other objects.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/snap.html#additional-snap-options). Does this help?